# how to select one row from one table and multiple rows from other table using joins in mysql,

Tags: php, mysql

I searched google and everything all are explained using joins but i dont need duplicate data of the first table, I want single row from first table.

consider table a has two column id and name

```
id | name

1  | jhon

2  | rock
```

and table b has two column id which is foreign key referencing table a's id and place

```
id | nickname

1  | steve

1  | smith

2  | kiran
```

And i want out put as

```
id | name | nickname

1  | jhon | steve

          | smith
```

Comment: you can concat the nickname on group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple inner `JOIN` to do this, e.g.:

```
SELECT ta.id, ta.name, tb.nicname
FROM tablea ta JOIN tableb tb ON ta.id = tb.id;
```

This would result in multiple records for one user, to get only one record, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT`, e.g.:

```
SELECT ta.id, ta.name, GROUP_CONCAT(tb.nicname)
FROM tablea ta JOIN tableb tb ON ta.id = tb.id
GROUP BY ta.id, ta.name;
```

**Update**

To get the expected output, you can define variables in query and use `IF` to return the values, e.g.:

```
SELECT IF(@previous = ta.id, '', ta.id) as id, IF(@previous = ta.id, '', ta.name) as name, 
tb.nickname, @previous := ta.id 
FROM table1 ta JOIN table2 tb ON ta.id = tb.id,
(SELECT @previous := '') a ;
```

This will return an extra column but you can ignore that while parsing the result.

Comment: Hello sir, first one giving duplicate data for tablea and i don't want to GROUP_CONCAT because by concating i am unable to get separate column data in my project. And i have multiple columns not 2 or 3 and i have to select * from both tables

Comment: So you want empty values for first two columns for subsequent rows if ids are same?